# mapboxgl: create a map without displaying it

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm learning how to use mapboxgl and was looking at the examples on the website but couldn't find one on how to create a map without displaying it. Is there a way of doing this? The example for displaying it is:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v8',
    center: [-103.59179687498357, 40.66995747013945],
    zoom: 3,
});
```

However, I just want to create the map first but not actually display it yet until I want to use it later. When I take out the "container" field when creating the mapboxgl object, the api gives me an error since it's trying to look for the container in my html page (although it's not there since I don't want to display it yet):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the `mapboxgl.Map` constructor, it will create the WebGL canvas element within the `container` you pass in as argument. So you need to pass in a valid container id.

To control the visibility of the map you can just show/hide the container div.

```
#map {
   display: none;
}
```

And then to display the map:

```
document.getElementById('#map').style.display = 'block';
```